# Is Sencha ExtJS association POST wrong?

Tags: extjs

So, I have a problem using Sencha ExtJs 4.1 Associations.

I have something like:

**Models**

```
Ext.define('Tpl.model.User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['Tpl.model.PostTemplate'],
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'postTemplate', type: 'int' }
    ],
    associations: [
        { type: 'belongsTo', name: 'postTemplate', model:'Tpl.model.PostTemplate', associationKey: 'postTemplate', primaryKey: 'id', foreignKey: 'postTemplate' }
    ]
});

and

Ext.define('Tpl.model.PostTemplate', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'blah', type: 'string' }
    ],

    associations: [
        { type: 'hasMany', model: 'Tpl.model.User' }
    ]

});
```

**Stores**

```
Ext.define('Tpl.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Tpl.model.User',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '../users',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Tpl.store.PostTemplate', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'Tpl.model.PostTemplate',
    autoLoad: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        //appendId: true,
        url: '../postTemplates/',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: ''
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I'm getting a POST like this:

```
{
    "postTemplate": 1,
    "id": 0,
    "name": "foo"
}
```

But I need a POST like this:

```
{
    "postTemplate": {
        "id": 1,
        "blah": "foo"
    },
    "id": 0,
    "name": "bar"
}
```

Also, the assessor function like "setPostTemplate" doesn't exist and I think it should be created automatically.

Already tried to something like " record.data.postTemplate = (...) " but I got an infinite loop throwing an execption...

Can someone please advise? Also, if you need something else that could be useful for the answer let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box the Associated objects are not serialized back to the server as you expect them .  This issue has been brought up many times. The best thing might be to follow this thread:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store

This thread talks about overriding getRecordData in the JSON writer class.